# Book with children disappearing and animal suicides

Tags: story-identification

The main character is in his early 20's bald, allergic to the sun. He resides in a town that has a lot of weird things going on such as the unexplained disappearance of many children. The main character's parents were scientists on the military base which is supposed to be closed/abandoned. However even weirder things happen on the base such as mass animal suicides. There is a band of chimpanzees who are not "normal" roaming the base.

I believe that the book was part of a series chronicling the adventures of the main character and his band of odd friends onto the base and what they find and experience there. The main character believes he and all the "not normal" animals are products of military research/experiments.

I read the book around 11 or 12 years ago.

Any help in discovering this book/series name is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This almost sounds like a Dean Koontz sort of story.

Answer (score 7):

It's [*Fear Nothing*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fear_Nothing) which is the 1st book in the *Moonlight Bay* trilogy (incomplete) by Dean Koontz.

> ***Fear Nothing*** is a novel released in 1998 by the best-selling author Dean Koontz. The book is the first installment in what is reported to be a three-part series of books, known as the Moonlight Bay Trilogy, featuring Christopher Snow, who suffers from the rare (but real) disease called XP (xeroderma pigmentosum). The second in the trilogy, *Seize the Night*, was released in 1999. No release date has yet been set for the release of the third book titled *Ride the Storm*. Fear Nothing is in several ways a successor to 1987 Koontz novel *Watchers*.

....

> Later, upon returning home, Christopher finds his father's gun on his bed, and an urgent message on his answering machine to call Angela Ferryman, a nurse and lifelong family friend. Orson, the family dog, is uncharacteristically digging holes in the garden. Christopher stops the pet and brings Orson along with him to see Angela, who reveals a strange story about a night several years ago when she encountered a strange rhesus monkey in her house, a terrifying creature which is recovered by mysterious military personnel. Before more is revealed, Angela is killed while in another room, and Chris barely escapes when unknown assailants set the house on fire.